# Nested If else Statement, operand expected

Tags: bash

If else statement nested in for loop. Operand expected. error token is:

Ubuntu Linux

```
for i in "${dir_path[@]}"; do
  if [ "$dir_path[i]" ]; then     <--- this line
     echo "$filename found, Directory: $i"
  else
     echo "$filename not found"
  fi
done
```

It finds the paths correctly but it displays error: "operand expected (error token is "first directory"

Comment: What do you expect that `"$dir_path[i]"` represents?

Comment: What's the value of `dir_path`? Your string is equivalent to `"${dir_path[0]}[i]"`; the `[i]` is treated *literally*.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve] so that everybody here can reproduce it without guessing. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over the indices of the array, use

```
for i in "${!dir_path[@]}" ; do
#           ^
```

To check whether the file exists, use `[ -f "${dir_path[i]}" ]` (for an array, or the same with `$i` for an associative array). What you have is always true as it checks whether the string `"$dir_path[i]"` is not empty, which it never is, as it always contains at least `[i]`.

Comment: They'd also need to use `"${dir_path[$i]}"` to access that index (curly braces mandatory, and `$i` needed if it's associative rather than indexed, which the question doesn't include enough information to definitively answer).

Comment: Thank you, indeed i have to use "${!dir_path[@]}" instead of "${dir_path[@]}". But the real issue was that i had to use echo "$filename found, Directory: ${dir_path[$i]}".  Thank you both Charles and choroba